# Compare Two Lists Via One Property Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections

Say I have the following:

```
    class Widget1{
        public int TypeID { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }

    class Widget2
    {
        public int TypeID { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
    }

    private void test()
    {
        List<Widget1> widgets1 = new List<Widget1>();
        List<Widget2> widgets2 = new List<Widget2>();
        List<Widget1> widgets1_in_widgets2 = new List<Widget1>();

        //some code here to populate widgets1 and widgets2

        foreach (Widget1 w1 in widgets1)
        {
            foreach (Widget2 w2 in widgets2)
            {
                if (w1.TypeID == w2.TypeID)
                {
                    widgets1_in_widgets2.Add(w1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using two foreach loops to compare the lists by TypeID to populate a third list.
Is there any other way using LINQ to compare these two lists via the TypeID? Perhaps using Interstect or some other function?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What you want here is a `Join`.

```
var widgets1_in_widgets2 = from first in widgest1
    join second in widgets2
    on first.TypeID equals second.TypeID
    select first;
```

`Intersect` can be more or less thought of as a special case of `Join` where the two sequences are of the same type, and can thus be applied for equality instead of needing a projection for each type to generate a key to compare.  Given your case, `Intersect` isn't an option.

If a particular ID is duplicated in your second set and you don't want the item to be duplicated in the results then you can use a `GroupJoin` instead of a `Join`:

```
var widgets1_in_widgets2 = from first in widgest1
    join second in widgets2
    on first.TypeID equals second.TypeID
    into matches
    where matches.Any()
    select first;
```

Comment: +1 _" Given your case, Intersect isn't an option"_ It would be an option when a custom `IEqualityComparer<BaseWidget>` would be possible, so a common base type. Then you could either pass that to [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) or override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` in `BaseWidget` to compare by `TypeID` by default.

Answer (score 64):

You can do this

```
widgets2.Where(y=>widget1.Any(z=>z.TypeID==y.TypeID));
```

Comment: While this will generate the proper output, it will have rather poor performance as you're doing a linear search on a collection for each item in another collection.

Comment: The simplest of changes is simply to store the TypeIDs of one of the sets in a `HashSet` which can be searched much more quickly.  A more significat change would be to just use `Join`, as I showed, although it will end up doing pretty much the same thing under the hood.

Comment: good query, shouldnt be a problem when using this with a small list.

Comment: Good and faster one

Answer (score 13):

I like this solution because it is simple to read in the code.

```
bool result = firstList.All(o => secondList.Any(w => w.Prop1 == o.Prop1 && w.Prop2 == o.Prop2));
```

See the full example in fiddle: [Fiddle example comparation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dTJk2l)

Comment: Thx, this worked for me.

 if (projectIds.All(y => r.ProjectsId.Any(z => z.Equals(y))))
                {
                    reports.Add(r);
                }

Comment: What if two lists are different?

Answer (score 5):

Join has the drawback that your results might be duplicated if widgets1 or widgets2 contains elements with the same TypeID more than one (which also applies to your original code, by the way).

The following will do exactly what you want: Return all elements from widgets1 for which an element with a corresponding TypeID exists in widgets2.

```
widgets1_in_widgets2 = (from w1 in widgets1
                        where widgets2.Any(w2 => w1.TypeID == w2.TypeID)
                        select w1).ToList()
```

Comment: While this will generate the proper output, it will have rather poor performance as you're doing a linear search on a collection for each item in another collection.

Comment: `"Join has the drawback that your results might be duplicated if widgets1 or widgets2 contains elements with the same TypeID more than one.`" The code in the OP would actually have the *exact* same output as a `Join`, so either he doesn't have duplicate keys in either list, or he *wants* the duplicated results.

Comment: @Servy: Good point, I'll mention that in my answer. Still, the variable naming makes me assume that this is unintentional.

Comment: If that's the issue you want to address then you can simply use a `GroupJoin`, which gives you the solution you're describing without the rather high performance cost of your answer.  Also note that, while I agree the variable naming would indicate he doesn't want duplicates in the results, he may not have duplicates in the second list, thus having no need to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using overload of "Where"

```
var isMatch = !widgets1.Where((w1, index) => w1.TypeId == widgets2[index].TypeId)).Any();
```

Comment: An answer with just code and no explanation, especially when the question has been thoroughly answered before

Comment: You could update this answer to specify how it is different.  I find this to be a helpful proposed solution in the case where you want to compare order and avoid any linear searching.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Linq's own `.Except()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0) to do the comparison for you, and bring back the "exception" or the inverse of what you expected.

```
newErr = errList.Except(hList).ToList();
```

Here I am *intersecting* an array `errList` with another array `hList`, and bringing back the inverse or the lines that did not exist in the `hList` array.

```
errList = "this is a new line"

hList =  ["first line","2nd line","3rd line"]
```

**Result**

```
newErr = "this is a new line"
```