# Compare 2 lists with different values

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to compare two lists of objects that contains different values but only one unique property **RefCode**

Example input:

> List 1
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenP", RefCode="MM01", year = 2015)
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenS", RefCode="MM02", year = 2015)
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenK", RefCode="MM03", year = 2014)
>
> List 2
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenP2", RefCode="MM01", year = 2016)
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenS3", RefCode="MM02", year = 2016)
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenKF", RefCode="MM15", year = 2016)

**Result should be**

> Product(CurrentName ="GenP", RefCode="MM01", year = 2015)
>
> Product(CurrentName ="GenS", RefCode="MM02", year = 2015)

Because these items can be found in List 2 based on RefCode
Using `Enumerable.Except` Doesn't work, i got 0 records when i compare the 2 lists.

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare Two Lists Via One Property Using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323804/compare-two-lists-via-one-property-using-linq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ `Where` and `Any` to do something like this:

```
var result =
    list1
    .Where(x => list2.Any(y => x.RefCode == y.RefCode))
    .ToList();
```

For performance reasons, you can use a `HashSet` like this:

```
//Create a hashset that contains all RefCodes from list2
var hashset = new HashSet<string>(list2.Select(x => x.RefCode));

var result =
    list1
    .Where(x => hashset.Contains(x.RefCode))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple LINQ-query:

```
list1.Where(x => list2.Any(v => v.RefCode == x.RefCode));
```

Answer (score 2):

One more alternative:

```
List<Product> result = products1.Join(products2, p1 => p1.RefCode, p2 => p2.RefCode, (p1, p2) => p1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) rather than `Distinct` but as you are only working on 1 field you need to use an `EqualityComparer`.

```
class Product
{
    public Product(string currentName, string refCode, int year)
    {
        CurrentName = currentName;
        RefCode = refCode;
        Year = year;
    }

    public string CurrentName { get; }
    public string RefCode { get; }
    public int Year { get;}
}

class ProductEqualityComparer : EqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public override bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        return x.RefCode.Equals(y.RefCode);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.RefCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class CompareEntriesFixture 
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void CompareEntries()
    {
        var list1 = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product("GenP", "MMO1", 2015),
            new Product("GenS", "MMO2", 2015),
            new Product("GenK", "MMO3", 2014),
        };

        var list2 = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product("GenP2", "MMO1", 2016),
            new Product("GenS3", "MMO2", 2016),
            new Product("GenKF", "MM15", 2016),
        };

        var expected = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product("GenP", "MMO1", 2015),
            new Product("GenS", "MMO2", 2015)
        };

        var common = list1.Intersect(list2, new ProductEqualityComparer()).ToList();

        CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, common, new ProductComparer());

    }

}
```