# C# compare two Lists by one Property and change value of first List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, logic

I have the following problem:
I have two Lists of type foo.
Now I want to Iterate through both lists as in the second list I have changed values of two Properties.
To clarify what I mean here's the code I know it would work:

```
foreach(foo bar in list_1) {
  foreach(foo bar2 in list_2) {
    if (bar.ID == bar2.ID) {
      bar.name = bar2.name;
      bar.color = bar2.color;
    }
  }
}
```

So as you see, the properties in list_2 do have other values as in list_1, but I need them also in list_1.
It would work that way, but I wonder if there would be an easier way to do this (maybe with LinQ?)

Kind regards,
Asat0r

Comment: This would probably be better-received on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: LINQ would be very much useful in this case. Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323804/compare-two-lists-via-one-property-using-linq

Comment: Easier - no. Faster - sure.

Comment: Is `ID` unique within the list?

Comment: @Mainak: I tried this solution, but couldn't get it properly to work for this case. although the answer of Dmitry Bychenko is working fine for me. But thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ID` is unique within `list_2` you can have a faster implementation (for large lists) by converting *list* to *dictionary*

```
  // A little bit of Linq: ToDictionary 
  var dict = list_2.ToDictionary(item => item.ID, item => item);
  ...
  foreach (item in list_1) {
    foo master;

    if (dict.TryGetValue(item.ID, out master)) {
      item.name = master.name; 
      item.color = master.color;
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, I forgot to mention that ID is unique in both lists :) thank you, this answer was what I was looking for, as I try to avoid capsuled for- or foreach-loops.