# Compare two struct List and find if item of list1 appears in item of list2 in C#

Tags: c#, list, struct, find, contains

I have two record structures and two lists as follows:

```
 public struct gtAliasRecType : ICloneable
    {
        public int lRecordNum; 
        public double dLocationCd; 
    }

   public struct gtCVARecType : ICloneable
    {
        public double dLocationCd; 
    }

    static public List<gtCVARecType> LCVARec = null; 
    static public List<gtAliasRecType> LAliasRec = null;
```

**Now i want to iterate "LAliasRec" list and find whether similar "dLocationCd" exists in "LCVARec" list or not.**

I tried using "Contains" and "Find" function of list[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1) but ended up in errors.

```
 public static void XYZ()
    {
        gtAliasRecType uAliasRec = gtAliasRecType.CreateInstance();
        gtCVARecType uCVARec = gtCVARecType.CreateInstance();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < LAliasRec.Count; i++)
        {
           uAliasRec = LAliasRec[i];               

            //trying Find method 
            gtCVARecType c1  = LCVARec.Find(uAliasRec.dLocationCd);

            //trying Contains method 
            bool nReturn = LCVARec.Contains( uAliasRec.dLocationCd );
            
        }
    }
```

**However, i ran into "Cannot convert from 'double' to 'gtCVARecType' error.**

[Contains & Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netcore-3.1)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please show us the *whole* code of what you've tried, and exactly what errors you saw. Basically, please provide a [mcve]. (I'd also note that mutable structs like this are usually a bad idea - I'd also generally recommend using properties instead of public fields, and following .NET naming conventions for everything.)

Comment: Can you share how  did you try to use contains and find? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: You can use LINQ. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare Two Lists Via One Property Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323804/compare-two-lists-via-one-property-using-linq)

Comment: Hello @ChetanRanpariya, i have updated the snapshot

Comment: Hello, @JonSkeet,  i have updated the snapshot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `Contains` to find an item of a different type. You *can* use `Find`, but I'd personally use the LINQ `Any` method:

```
foreach (var uAliasRec in LAliasRec)
{
    bool nReturn = LCVARec.Any(rec => rec.dLocationCd == uAliasRec.dLocationCd);
    // Presumably do something with nReturn
}
```

If the lists are large, you might want to create a `HashSet<double>` for all the locations first, which is an up-front cost that will make everything else cheaper:

```
HashSet<double> locations = new HashSet<double>(LCVARec.Select(rec => rec.dLocationCd));
foreach (var uAliasRec in LAliasRec)
{
    bool nReturn = locations.Contains(uAliasRec.dLocationCd);
    // Presumably do something with nReturn
}
```

As an aside, I'd *strongly* advise you to start following regular .NET naming conventions. In its current form, your code is going to be very hard for anyone used to regular C# code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and [Inner join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) to find the intersection of two lists.

```
var query = from lcva in LCVARec
            join lAlias in LAliasRec on lcva.dLocationCd equals lAlias.dLocationCd
            select lcva;

Console.WriteLine(query.Count()); //prints number of matching items.
```

**Update**

If you can change the `List<T>` to `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` of `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` it will help in quicker lookup.

If you prefer to use `Contains()` you must implement `IEquatable<T>` and if you want performance you have to `Sort()` which needs the class to have `IComparable<T>` and then do `BinarySearch`

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1#remarks

Comment: Hello @Ramesh , i am working on performance issue and using LINQ query can degrade the performance when compare to "Find" or "Contains" function. As i might have items upto 70k in the list.

Comment: 1. If Performance is critical, why not store them in Dictonary with dLocatoinCd as key?

Comment: 2. Did you measure the LINQ query to confirm if the performance is hit? This might be same as the forloop + Find / Contains

Comment: @AbhishekSingh - Please take a look at updated answer

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Intersect`

```
 var results = LAliasRec
     .Select(x => x.dLocationCd)
     .Intersect(LCVARec.Select(x => x.dLocationCd));
 bool exists = results.Count() > 0;
```

`Select` only the double values, and get intersected ones. If `Count` **greater than 0**, you got mutual property values.

Comment: Hello @Berkay, Thanks for the quick response. However, i am working on performance issue and using of "Intersect" and "Select" can degrade the performance when compare to "Find" or "Contains" function. Your code works well, but it even sort the "dLocationCd" values in some particular order when compared to the  list "dLocationCd" values order.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh: If performance is so critical, you should mention that in the question - including benchmarks for solutions that give the right answer, and concrete performance criteria.